# Why don't Sass respect the order of CSS property using nested media query?

Tags: css, sass

Why don't Sass respect the order of CSS property using nested media query?

Input Sass:
`margin-top: 3px` appears after the media query.

```
.myContainer {
  margin: 1px;

  @media only screen and (min-width: 768) {
    margin: 2px;
  };

  margin-top: 3px;
}
```

Output CSS:
`margin-top: 3px` now appears before the media query.

```
.myContainer {
  margin: 1px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768) {
  .myContainer {
     margin: 2px;
  }
}
```

In this example, you can see that the position of `margin-top:3px` is changed.

How could this happen and is it expected?

Comment: Why is it a problem that `margin-top: 3px` is before the media query? I think it is expected. Otherwise you would have to rules instead of one, so it wouldn't be as small.

Comment: `margin: 2px;` overrides your margin top of 3px as it is shorthand for 2px margin on all sides - it is expected

Answer (score 0):

It is the expected result. Otherwise, it will have to create two separate classes like in the second snippet below. This wouldn't make sense. Try this:

```
.myContainer {
  margin: 1px;

  @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    margin: 2px;
  };

  & {
    margin-top: 3px;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
.myContainer {
  margin: 1px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .myContainer {
    margin: 2px;
  }
}
.myContainer {
  margin-top: 3px;
}
```